# Stacked Charts in modern UI Metro WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Can someone explain to me how to create a stacked bar graph using Morder UI (Metro) Charts (http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/) in wpf.

if I do the following XAML;

```
 <metroChart:StackedBar100Chart d:IsLocked="True" Name="f" >
                <metroChart:StackedBar100Chart.Series>
                    <metroChart:ChartSeries  DisplayMember="Name"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ExampleValues}"
                        ValueMember="Count" />
                </metroChart:StackedBar100Chart.Series>
  </metroChart:StackedBar100Chart>
```

I can bind to an observable collection of numbers - however how do i add a second stack, third stack etc..

Adding a new series adds more bars;

```
 <metroChart:StackedBar100Chart d:IsLocked="True">
                    <metroChart:StackedBar100Chart.Series>
                        <metroChart:ChartSeries  DisplayMember="Name"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding ExampleValues}"
                            ValueMember="Count" />
                        <metroChart:ChartSeries  DisplayMember="Name"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding ExampleValues2}"
                            ValueMember="Count" />
                    </metroChart:StackedBar100Chart.Series>
  </metroChart:StackedBar100Chart>

 exampleValues.Add(new ExampleValues() { Name = "China", Count = 1340 });
        exampleValues.Add(new ExampleValues() { Name = "India", Count = 1220 });
        exampleValues.Add(new ExampleValues() { Name = "United States", Count = 309 });
        exampleValues.Add(new ExampleValues() { Name = "Indonesia", Count = 240 });
        exampleValues.Add(new ExampleValues() { Name = "Brazil", Count = 195 });
        exampleValues.Add(new ExampleValues() { Name = "Pakistan", Count = 174 });
        exampleValues.Add(new ExampleValues() { Name = "Nigeria", Count = 158 });

        exampleValues2.Add(new ExampleValues() { Name = "England", Count = 860 });
        exampleValues2.Add(new ExampleValues() { Name = "Scotland", Count = 600 });
        exampleValues2.Add(new ExampleValues() { Name = "Wales", Count = 209 });
```

[image]

how do I stack on top of an existing bar?

What I want to produce is something like this for each example country;

[image]

Comment: just to clarify by stack i mean differnt bock within the same series

Comment: You can add multiple `<ChartSeries>` to your `Series`

Comment: Sybren can you provide an example? isnt multipe series going to create multiple lines? what I want to know is how to have 1 bar with multiple blocks onit

Comment: I think you also have to bind your `Series` element to a collection.

Answer (score 0):

The `Series` element is a collection, so you can just add another `ChartSeries`:

```
<metroChart:StackedBar100Chart.Series>
    <metroChart:ChartSeries DisplayMember="Name"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding ExampleValues}"
                            ValueMember="Count" />

    <!-- You can add more series elements here. -->
    <metroChart:ChartSeries DisplayMember="Name"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding AnotherCollection}"
                            ValueMember="Count" />
</metroChart:StackedBar100Chart.Series>
```

Comment: Hi Mike - that seems to add new bars - and I want to know how to stack on an existing bar (I have edited the question)

Comment: You can either add the items to the existing collection, or perhaps you can edit the `Style` so that the margins between the series isn't so large.